# ming swf library how to install in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation

Can someone please explain how to install ming in an Ubuntu 10.0.4 (Lucid) environment? I've been hearing really amazing things about this package, but I can't get it to install correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get install libming-util libming-dev
```

If that doesn't work, be specific about what errors you're getting.

Comment: Yep that worked :) so.. I'm trying to compile the simple 'hello world' example given on the home page at http://mingruby.rubyforge.org/ ...but i keep running into an error regarding unknown headers. How would I need to change this to make it work with libming? btw, sorry if this seems like a really dumb question.. kinda new at this.

Comment: Hey Matthew. The error I got was "ming.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- ming/ming (LoadError) from ming.rb:1